# How to disable default notification alert view on iOS remote notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

In my app I enabled remote notifications,

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0")){
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
        if( !error ){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
    }];
}else{
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

And I implemented the delegate methods as follows,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Failed!!");
}


 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application   didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // Print message.
    if (userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo);
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

But when the app is in foreground and receiving a notification, I got a UIAlertView with the notification title and message. I want to

```
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

//Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center       didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response    withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler();
}
```

I debugged on `willPresentNotification:` and after this triggers I got the alert. And I tested by removing this method as well. But still this alert is showing when receiving a notification.

How may I disable this alert view? I'm using 10.2 iOS in my iPhone

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by disabling? not see the alert at all?! you mean convert it to a silent push?

Comment: yes. not see the alert.

Comment: "you mean convert it to a silent push?" yes. I don't need to show the alert

Comment: This is very odd. AFAIK you should NEVER see an alert when you are in foreground. Not sure why it happens

Comment: Added the alert what I got.

Comment: You said "I debugged on willPresentNotification: and after this triggers I got the alert." do you mean by using *step over* of your debugging you just arrived to this alert?

Comment: yes. Once the completion block is done, the alert triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `UIAlertController` comes from notifications. Are you sure you are not creating one elsewhere ?

Your notifications' implementation seems ok.

Can you search in your project and using breakpoints to see if any of your  `UIAlertController`s get hit?

Comment: Can you CMD+Shift+ F (global project research) for every clues about this AlertView. For example you can search "initWithTitle: "Alert"" or "message:"Alert"". Anything in order to find this AlertView.

Comment: I did. But there are no alerts like that

Comment: did you try for all AlertControllers ? I made an edit on his answer. he previously had it for AlertView...

Comment: @Honey Thank you, was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone in the completionHandler

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}
```